# converting string vector with special character to factor

Tags: r

I have a Stata `dta` raw data file that includes a string vector with `…`. Once imported into R using the `foreign` package, my data look like the following:

```
# dput(dat[1:3, 218])
# c("", "I want very much\xc9will do whatever it takes", "I want very much\xc9will do my fair share"
```

For this example, I'll create an object called `test`:

```
test <- c("", "I want very much\xc9will do whatever it takes", "I want very much\xc9will do my fair share")
```

I want to convert `test` to a factor, but I just get all NAs. I've tried two approaches:

```
factor(test,
       levels=c("I want very much\\xc9will do whatever it takes",
                "I want very much\\xc9will do my fair share"),
       labels=c(1, 2))
# [1] <NA> <NA> <NA>
# Levels: 1 2

factor(test,
       levels=c("I want very much…will do whatever it takes",
                "I want very much…will do my fair share"),
       labels=c(1, 2))
# [1] <NA> <NA> <NA>
# Levels: 1 2
```

I know I could edit the `dta` file, but I don't want to touch the raw data. What else can I try?

In the end, I want the following:

```
#[1] <NA> 1    2   
#Levels: 1 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\\` to escape your special characters. This works:

```
factor(test,
       levels=c("I want very much\xc9will do whatever it takes",
                "I want very much\xc9will do my fair share"),
       labels=c(1, 2))

#[1] <NA> 1    2   
#Levels: 1 2
```

Comment: +1. I didn't notice that the `levels` used are different from the strings in the `test`

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the double `\\` displayed in R output.

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- c(NA, "I want very much\xc9will do my fair share", "I want very much\xc9will do whatever it takes")

ana <- as.factor(test)

library(plyr)

bob <- revalue(ana, c("I want very much\xc9will do my fair share" = "1",
                  "I want very much\xc9will do whatever it takes" = "2"))
bob
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: factors with labels 1 and 2. but the levels i define are not found because of the encoding issue.

Comment: OK; i think you have É in test: Is that right? I created the following. Then, I called as.factor. I can see all letters fine and all levels appeared on my machine. Am I getting what you want? `test2 <- c("ɮÉèèéé", "I want very much\xc9will do whatever it takes", "I want very much\xc9will do my fair share")`

Comment: not quite. i want your `test2[2]` and `test2[3]` to have labels 1 and 2, respectively.

Comment: I am trying to reach you. Are you saying that you want to change the names of the factors? Like "I want very much\xc9will do my fair share" to "1", for example?

Comment: thanks for taking an interest. i edited my question to show my desired output. i hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: If i had `test3 <- c("", "hi", "bye")` and then ran `factor(test3, levels=c("hi", "bye"), labels=c(1, 2))` it would give me `#[1] <NA> 1    2`. The first element would not be found, so it would be NA. The second element `hi` would match the level `hi`, so it would be 1. The third element `bye` would match the level `bye`, so it would be 2.

Comment: It seems that you found your way!

Comment: Not really. I posted my last comment before seeing your edit. I was just trying to further clarify my desired output. Your new `revalue()` approach seems to work for the toy example, but I can't get it to run on my real data. I think it's because I have an underlying encoding issue.

Comment: How about `iconv()` then? Here is a [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html).

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your expected output, may be:

```
 factor(as.vector(setNames(1:2,unique(test[test!='']))[test]))
 #[1] <NA> 1    2   
 #Levels: 1 2
```

Just noticed from @thelatemail's reply that your `levels` don't match with the `test` string.  For example.

```
 test1 <- c("", "I want very much\\xc9will do whatever it takes", "I want very much\\xc9will do my fair share")  #using `\\`
 factor(test1, levels= unique(test1[test1!='']), labels=1:2)
 #[1] <NA> 1    2   
 #Levels: 1 2
```

If you do:

```
 factor(test1, levels= unique(test[test!='']), labels=1:2)
 #[1] <NA> <NA> <NA>
 #Levels: 1 2
```